# Will this leak memory?

Tags: c, string, malloc

I made a small function to catenate strings and return the combined string. However since I assign memory to a third variable in the function, will the memory be freed when the function finishes or will it stay there, requiring me to free it later? and if I need to free it, what's the most stylish solution to do it?

Here's the test code. It works, but I can't tell if that memory is freed or not with my tools.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char * StrCat(const char *st1, const char *st2){
    char *string = calloc((strlen(st1) + strlen(st2) + 1), sizeof(char));
    strcat(string, st1);
    strcat(string, st2);
    return string;
}

int main(){
    printf("String: %s\n", StrCat("HELLO ", "WORLD"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I did this function to automate everything and making my life easier at code. But notice StrCat is capitalized, it's not the standard strcat call.

Comment: Just noticed it now, 'StrCat' resembles 'strcat'. I recommended calling it 'myStrCat'.

Comment: Oh, it's intentional, I work well with it, and did with other string functions. But if you consider it bad practice I'll change it.

Comment: You should check the return value from calloc() before using it. Yes, the code leaks the allocated memory - but the system reclaims it as the program exits. Here, it doesn't matter; in a big, long-running program (eg a database server or a web server), it would matter a lot.

Comment: The capitalization makes it clear that StrCat() is not identical to strcat() - but also suggests that it is related to strcat().  Personally, I find 'my' as a prefix annoying - childish, even.

Comment: Jonathan: I am using it into a game, and I need to catenate strings to send them to a control handler (There's a reason to use strings there). I needed to be really sure I was going the right thing so I wrote this small function separate from the main engine. Well, I will figure out how to free that memory in an elegant way (I'd like to just call the function and not having to free it from outside it)

Answer (score 13):

Yes you need to free it.

Probably something like:

```
int main(){
    char *s = StrCat("HELLO ", "WORLD");
    printf("String: %s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: calloc zeroes out the memory, so there's no need for an extra memset or whatever (there _would_ be had @DalGr used malloc instead, but that's not what he did).

Comment: calloc sets the memory to zeroes

Comment: I forgot about the implementation of calloc(); Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since the applications ends right after printf, there's really no need to free it, since the application will do that for you when it dies. But yes, it's always good practice to free it.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, but its this kind of thinking that gets people into trouble. Especially beginners.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to free it. Try valgrind to detect the leak.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you call calloc, malloc, new, etc. a call to a function that frees the memory must also be made.

Answer (score 2):

memory leaks and free memory this is tricky problems. may be worth trying the debugger? I use deleaker for solving such problems.